# Increase a certain time by a day?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm looking to increase a specific time of the day using (MFC classes) [`CTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78zb0ese%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [`CTimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ay6ws8h3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). What i'm aiming to do is use CTimeSpan to increase the time given in time1() by a day set by `CTime time1`.

How do I link up

```
CTime time1(2012, 4, 1, 1, 0, 0);
```

with

```
CTimeSpan span1(1, 0, 0, 0);
```

so that `CTimeSpan::CTimeSpan` increases the day by 1 using the date given by time1?

Comment: C++ has no type `CTime` or `CTimeSpan`. Try again.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7zw4wy1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Is a day defined as 86400 seconds or do you wish to account for leap seconds ?

Answer (score 5):

`CTime` appears to have an `operator+=` that takes a `CTimeSpan` argument.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a0edhd0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

So:

```
time1 += span1;
```

Answer (score -1):

What about:

```
CTime result = CTime(input.GetYear(), input.GetMonth(), input.GetDay() + span.GetDays(), input.GetHour() + span.GetHours(), input.GetMinute + span.GetMinutes());
```

CTime is a ATL/MFC Class, defined here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78zb0ese(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: The documentation I found (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6989cds%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) suggests that CTime's constructor demands a valid range for all those arguments, which you may not be giving it.  Don't feel bad though--Microsoft made a similar mistake recently that took down their cloud service! http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/03/09/summary-of-windows-azure-service-disruption-on-feb-29th-2012.aspx